# Hide/Show buttons tied to counter

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show

I have a counter on my site and two buttons, button1 and button2. I want button1 to show and button2 to be gone (invisible and not clickable) when counter = 1. And I want button2 to appear and button1 to be gone when the counter = 2.

I'm trying something like this in pure js but it's not working:

```
if (counter === 1) {
document.getElementById('button2').disabled=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully one of these suggestions is what you're looking for. Good luck!

Hard coded disabling/enabling:
http://jsfiddle.net/jeZSa/

Same as above except using CSS to hide/show buttons:
http://jsfiddle.net/WKYyh/1/

CSS

```
.hidden { display:none; visibility:hidden; }
```

HTML

```
<button id="button1" onClick="enableBtn1()">Button ONE</button>
<button id="button2" onClick="enableBtn2()" class="hidden">Button TWO</button>
```

JS

```
enableBtn1 = function() {
    document.getElementById('button1').className = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('button2').className = '';
}

enableBtn2 = function() {
    document.getElementById('button1').className = '';
    document.getElementById('button2').className = 'hidden';
}
```

-EDIT- Here's a visible/invisible version without using CSS:
http://jsfiddle.net/kF7yh/

Comment: actually it's still not working. the buttons are position: absolute in my CSS file. would that be preventing them from being hidden?